# Regular expression to help in splitting a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, split

I have a string in the following format:

**files** = `" \r\n     6 : size=70 : <Message body> \r\n    4 : size=3 : Test.txt \r\n    17 : size=24 : Test2.txt"`

I want to write a regular expression to strip out all of the whitespace, and then split the string into an array of strings as follows:

**stringArray[0]** = `"6:size=70:<Message body>"`

**stringArray[1]** = `"4:size=3:Test.txt"`

**stringArray[2]** = `"17:size=24:Test2.txt"`

I am trying to do it like this:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\s", RegexOptions.Compiled);
files = pattern.Replace(files, String.Empty);
string[] scores = files.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

But the problem is that my regular expression strips even "\r\n", so I can't possibly split it up by Environment.NewLine, so how can I achieve this behavior?

**Edit**: I overlooked one thing. I want to keep whitespace when splitting in `<Message body>` or any other split strings, so I actually need to keep whitespace after the first character of the last colon but before the last character of \r\n...for example, `<Message body>` or `Test 3.txt` should preserve whitespace.

**Edit**: I would like to use a regular expression first, before splitting,

Comment: You can split it first and THEN remove the whitespace.  But "Message body" has whitespace in it, so do you really want to remove the whitespace?

Comment: Is this what are you looking for? [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lI3jH0/1)

Comment: @KyleW No, I suppose I overlooked this fact, I want to keep the whitespace in Message body.

Comment: @KyleW Sorry about that, I edited the question.

Comment: @user3218114 Sorry about that, not quite. I edited the question!

Comment: @KyleW It would be much more performant to run through this regular expression before splitting.

Comment: @Alexandru and yet the performance is unlikely to matter.

Comment: @KyleW Performance is likely to matter...hence why I'm trying to do it this way, with the regex first, then the split.

Comment: @Alexandru Why is performance likely to matter for this tiny piece of processing?  What is the performance characteristics of running it through a regex vs.. whatever other solution is there?  Unless you've done the profiling and determined that this is a bottleneck, then it's not.  Anyway, I provided a solution down below that fits the requirements.  It could probably be cleaned up a bit.

Comment: @KyleW My files string can get quite large...this was just a way for me to simplify the question on Stack, but I thought I was pretty clear about doing the regex first, that's why I titled my question the way I did. Not that there's anything functionally wrong with your solution, but I want it with the regex first for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In regular expressiions '\s'matches whitespace characters including new line so to avoid removing new lines replace \s with a single space " " This should give you the desired behavior

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@" ", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach without regex.

```
string x = " \r\n     6 : size=70 : <Message body> \r\n    4 : size=3 : Test.txt \r\n    17 : size=24 : Test2.txt";

string[] scores = x.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(p => p.Trim())
            .Where(p => p!=string.Empty).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

From you're stated input/output, it looks to me what you really want to do is to split on each \r\n, then selectively replace the spaces.

If you have the need to do regex->split, then here is a solution that will work (given the very limited input).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = " \r\n     6 : size=70 : <Message body> \r\n    4 : size=3 : Test.txt \r\n    17 : size=24 : Test2.txt";
        var pattern = "\n.*";

        var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern);

        while (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value.Trim().Replace(" : ", ":"));
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Alternatively, here is a one line solution, though much less readable, IMO:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = " \r\n     6 : size=70 : <Message body> \r\n    4 : size=3 : Test.txt \r\n    17 : size=24 : Test2.txt";
        var pattern = "\n.*";

        Regex.Matches(s, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value.Trim().Replace(" : ", ":")).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: `-1` no need for a while loop this can be done using Split Function

Comment: While satisfying this constraint? "Edit: I would like to use a regular expression first, before splitting."

Also, you're solution strips the space between "<Message" and "body>".

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = " \r\n     6 : size=70 : <Message body> \r\n    4 : size=3 : Test.txt \r\n    17 : size=24 : Test 2.txt";

var split = s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var results = split.Select(x => 
{
    var lastColonIndex = x.LastIndexOf(":");
    int nonWhiteSpaceIndex = lastColonIndex + 1;
    for(; nonWhiteSpaceIndex < x.Length; ++nonWhiteSpaceIndex)
    {
        if(!char.IsWhiteSpace(x[nonWhiteSpaceIndex]))
        {
            nonWhiteSpaceIndex.Dump();
            break;
        }
    }
    return (x.Substring(0, nonWhiteSpaceIndex).Replace(" ", "") + x.Substring(nonWhiteSpaceIndex)).Trim();
}).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Dump();
```

Comment: very long way of doing something that can be done essentially in 1 line

Comment: yes it does I am not sure what you're talking about perhaps you did not run the code to test it yourself I just ran it and I yield the same results that the OP does per what he was expecting

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yup, I ran it.  Doesn't keep that space.